# Android Espresso. How to check ErrorText in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-espresso

Basically I am trying to test that after login incorrectly I have an error showing in the email field.

The view is:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/ti_email"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/authentication_email_placeholder"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="@string/placeholder_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I try to do it like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.et_email))
    .check(matches(hasErrorText(
        ctx.getString(R.string.authentication_error_empty_email))));
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This works with a CustomMatcher:

```
public static Matcher<View> hasTextInputLayoutErrorText(final String expectedErrorText) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (!(view instanceof TextInputLayout)) {
                return false;
            }

            CharSequence error = ((TextInputLayout) view).getError();

            if (error == null) {
                return false;
            }

            String hint = error.toString();

            return expectedErrorText.equals(hint);
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Couldn't figure out why the Espresso `hasErrorText` matcher wouldn't work, but this custom matcher works perfectly

Comment: Thanks, bro!! You made my day!

Comment: massive thumbs up

Answer (score 6):

I think that you would like to set error on **TextInputLayout** not on **EditText**. If it is correct, in the following way you could achieve this.

```
 onView(withId(R.id.ti_email)).check(matches(hasDescendant(
    withText(ctx.getString(R.string.authentication_error_empty_email))))
 )
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write a Custom Matcher:

```
public final class CustomItemMatchers {

private static class TextInputLayoutErrorMatcher extends BoundedMatcher<Object, Wrapper> {

  private final Matcher<String> itemTextMatcher;

  public TextInputLayoutErrorMatcher(final Matcher<String> itemTextMatcher){
     super(TextInputLayout.class);
     this.itemTextMatcher = itemTextMatcher;
  }

  @Override
  public void describeTo(Description description) {
     description.appendText("with error  content: ");
     itemTextMatcher.describeTo(description);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean matchesSafely(TextInputLayout til) {
     if (til == null) {
        return false;
     }
     return itemTextMatcher.matches((til.getError());
  }
}

public static Matcher<Object> withErrorName(final Matcher<String> itemTextMatcher) {
  checkNotNull(itemTextMatcher);
  return new TextInputLayoutErrorMatcher(itemTextMatcher);
}
}
```

You can use it then with

```
matches(CustomItemMatchers.withErrorName(equalTo("My Error")))
```

This code was written with Espresso 1, but I hope it still works.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a custom matcher, in Kotlin you can get the same result by

```
    val expectedString = ctx.getString(R.string.authentication_error_empty_email)
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.ti_email))
        .check { view, _ ->
            val actualError = (view as TextInputLayout).error
            assertEquals(actualError, expectedError)
        }

}
```

I like this way best because it allows flexibility with any view

Answer (score 0):

wrote a custom matcher

```
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

public class TextInputLayoutErrorMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<View>{

private String expectedErrorText;

TextInputLayoutErrorMatcher(String expectedErrorText) {
    this.expectedErrorText = expectedErrorText;
}

@Override
protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {

    if (!(item instanceof TextInputLayout)) {
        return false;
    }

    CharSequence error = ((TextInputLayout) item).getError();

    if (error == null) {
        return false;
    }

    String hint = error.toString();

    return expectedErrorText.equals(hint);
}

@Override
public void describeTo(Description description) {
    description.appendText("with error text " + expectedErrorText);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Its working :)

```
onView(withId(R.id.et_email)).check(matches(hasErrorText("Error Message")));
```

Comment: no its not, com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Answer (score -6):

Please use setError() method of EditText 
Ex : EditText emailEditText;

```
if(invalidLogin)
    emailEditText.setError("Error Message");
```