# Testing EditText errors with Espresso on Android

Tags: android, testing, junit4, android-espresso

I want to test if an EditText field has an error (set with editText.setError("Cannot be blank!")).

[image: EditText field with error]

I've created an Espresso test case with the new AndroidStudio 2.2 feature, to record Espresso tests. So the code is pretty much auto-generated. But for now it only checks if the editText is displayed.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class CreateNoteActivityTitleCannotBeBlank {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<CreateNoteActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(CreateNoteActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void createNoteActivityTitleCannotBeBlank() {
        ViewInteraction floatingActionButton = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.fab_add_note),
                        withParent(allOf(withId(R.id.activity_create_note),
                                withParent(withId(android.R.id.content)))),
                        isDisplayed()));
        floatingActionButton.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction editText = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.tiet_note_title),
                        childAtPosition(
                                childAtPosition(
                                        withId(R.id.til_title),
                                        0),
                                0),
                        isDisplayed()));
        editText.check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    }

    private static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
            final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Is there a way to test if the error is displayed?

Comment: try add adnotation
@Nullable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Espresso. How to check ErrorText in TextInputLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285782/android-espresso-how-to-check-errortext-in-textinputlayout)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You change `editText.check(matches(isDisplayed()));` to `editText.check(matches(hasErrorText("Cannot be blank!")));`

Comment: Ya thats it! :) Thank you. I only checked the [Cheat Sheet](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/cheatsheet/) but there are missing some methods.

Comment: assertFalse(hasErrorText("ERROR").matches(editText));

Comment: What if I need to pass a string resource?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me under

```
        onView(withId(R.id.signin_email)).check(matches(hasErrorText("Email not valid")));
```