# test Case to check that user should not have special character in the text field

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have a test case that will check that user should not have special character in the text field.For example:-if I enter user1 in the first name and click in submit button it gives me an error message I should not have a special character in the text field what should I do to automate in espresso.

This error message i want to automate

[image]

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class T2W_0014 {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SplashScreenActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(SplashScreenActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void t2W_0014() {
        ViewInteraction customButton2 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.btn_signup), withText("Sign up"), isDisplayed()));
        customButton2.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction customEditText = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.first_name), isDisplayed()));
        customEditText.perform(click());

        ViewInteraction customEditText2 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.first_name), isDisplayed()));
        customEditText2.perform(replaceText("abhisek1"), closeSoftKeyboard());

        ViewInteraction customEditText3 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.last_name), isDisplayed()));
        customEditText3.perform(replaceText("numeric2"), closeSoftKeyboard());

        ViewInteraction customButton3 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.btn_signup), withText("Sign up"), isDisplayed()));
        customButton3.perform(click());
    }
}
```

Comment: After you edit your question to include the information that you incorrectly posted as answers, I will answer your question. Feel free to ping me after you have made the edits.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check the special character available or not!

```
public boolean isAlpha(String name) {
    return name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}
```

will return false if there is any special character in the name!

Comment: Note that this method should be part if the app and used during input validation.

Comment: I am doing automation of android apps in espresso I am now able to get what I should write so that my test case will not fail I am not able to check that error message

Answer (score 0):

You can use Espresso to verify that an `EditText` has the correct error message displayed, use [`hasErrorText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#hasErrorText(java.lang.String)):

```
customEditText.check(matches(hasErrorText("Name should only contain characters")));
```

See also [Testing EditText errors with Espresso on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206599/testing-edittext-errors-with-espresso-on-android) and [Android Espresso. How to check ErrorText in TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285782/android-espresso-how-to-check-errortext-in-textinputlayout).

I strongly suggest that you write a single test method for each `EditText` in your layout. This way you can individually verify that each one works correctly.

Comment: I am doing automation of android apps in espresso I am now able to get what I should write so that my test case will not fail

Comment: @AbhisekMohapatra You should edit your question to describe the exact steps of your test case and show the code you have written for it. Be sure to describe how the results differ from what you want.

Comment: Testcase:- Check the Acceptance of value like "Only Numbers" in Sign Up page first name and last name field

Step to reproduce
 1:Launch android application 
2:flash Screen appear 
3: Click on to the Signup button 
4:Enter only Numbers or Special characters in "first name field"
5: Enter only numbers or Special characters in"Last name field" 
6: Click on to Sign up button 


Expected result:-
One alert messages should display like "Name Should contains only character"

Comment: @AbhisekMohapatra Please edit your question. Also show what code you have written for the test do far.