# Testing validation in Android

Tags: android, validation, material-design, android-espresso

Hi having issues getting this to work, want to click on login button and test that the validation errors appear. I am using material design validations, this is what I have written

```
   @Test
    public void click_login_with_empty_fields_gives_errors() {

        onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.login_email2)).check(matches(hasErrorText("Email Field cannot be empty")));
        onView(withId(R.id.login_password2)).check(matches(hasErrorText("Password field cannot be empty")));
    }
```

The error I get is

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with error: is "Password field cannot be empty"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with error: is "Password field cannot be empty"
Got: "TextInputEditText{id=2131362003, res-name=login_password2, visibility=VISIBLE, width=996, height=141, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're matching a `TextInputEditText` in `onView(Matcher)` call instead of a `TextInputLayout`. The error text is set in `TextInputLayout` and not its child `EditText`. See [this test](https://github.com/ashutoshgngwr/noice/blob/497559bee2fdff9f697a090cce7b0a4e1c2ec022/app/src/androidTest/java/com/github/ashutoshgngwr/noice/fragment/DialogFragmentTest.kt#L97-L129).

**Edit**: You should also checkout [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34286462/2410641) where it is suggested to use a custom matcher instead of `hasErrorText()`.

Comment: Thanks was trying for hours but got the custom matcher to work finally